# Android, Launcher/open 3rd party native App from Webbrowser (Whatapps, Line, Facebbok, Viber)

Tags: java, android, html, performance, android-intent

Is there a way you can Launcher a App that is installed on Android from the web browser ?

In my website I want to add two button, whatapps and Facebook. When the user click on them. it will load the native app from the user device. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatsapp, the link is `href="whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com"` and for facebook, try the [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I find all the correct links for others messaging apps, i.e, line, viber....

Comment: @Joolah Try Google. Its easy. Thats what I did -.-